# beginning NServiceBus and dependancy injection and instances

Tags: c#-4.0, nservicebus

Im having some problems with NServiceBus, I can get the pubsub example working fine, but now I'm trying to integrate it into a production project and I cant get the thing to work!

My publisher code is exactly the same as the publisher example (I've just imported the project to rule out any other issues) but I then create a void function and call it from my WPF app and I get a "you cant call bus without creating an instance of bus" error

```
 public void RunTest()
            {
                    var eventMessage = new MarketPriceMessage();
                    eventMessage.Ticker = "IBM";
                    eventMessage.DataType = "Bid";
                    eventMessage.Value = (decimal)23.23423;
                    eventMessage.EventId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    eventMessage.Time = DateTime.Now; // > 30 ? (DateTime?)DateTime.Now : null;
                    eventMessage.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(99999D);



                    Bus.Publish(eventMessage);
            }
```

Any ideas as to whats going on there and where I'm going wrong?

Following @Adam's comments below this is the code I'm using internally in my WPF App:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    public IBus bus { get; set; }

     protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        NServiceBus.Configure.With()
               .Log4Net()
               .SpringBuilder()
               .XmlSerializer()
               .MsmqTransport()
               .UnicastBus()
               .LoadMessageHandlers()
               .CreateBus()
               .Start();
    }
}
```

}

and

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher { }

}
```

and

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class SubscriptionAuthorizer : IAuthorizeSubscriptions
    {
        public bool AuthorizeSubscribe(string messageType, string clientEndpoint, string clientWindowsIdentity, IDictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool AuthorizeUnsubscribe(string messageType, string clientEndpoint, string clientWindowsIdentity, IDictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

App Config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
  </configSections>

  <MsmqTransportConfig 
                       InputQueue="WpfApplication2InputQueue" 
                       ErrorQueue="error" 
                       NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" 
                       MaxRetries="5"/>
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <!--DistributorControlAddress="" DistributorDataAddress="" ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="">-->
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

When I'm stepping through my code I can see that bus is a null object.

I am including the references as normal

Comment: Are you bootstrapping NSB in your WPF app some where?  With WPF you will be self-hosting and therefore need to build up NSB on your own.

Comment: How would one do that? I have been trying for nearly a week on this! The latest message I'm getting is that it cant find a endpoint configuration file but everything is in the exe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with WPF, but it looks like there is an Application.Startup event that may work.  You need to "manually" configure the bus as shown here in the [docs](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/)

Comment: thanks, there is that event but I when I try that method I get a null bus instance, it doesnt look like NSB is injecting the object? I've tried this in worker classes as well.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to bootstrap?  Sounds like you may be missing something simple.

Comment: I think I've figured it out!!!!! I wasnt starting the the class that held all the NSB stuff, I was just calling it after instantiating it. I guess IWantToRunAtStartUp doesnt get called when you call the class constructors?

I guess I've got to leave the generic NSB host running in a loop while my app does stuff and publishes when it requires? Is there a best practise here?

Comment: Yes, you have to hang on to a reference to IBus somewhere globally.  If you are using a container you could use that same container for NSB.

Comment: Yeah I think my problem was not really understanding Dependency injection, but I've got it to work pretty much now so will cross that bridge later!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Autofac or some other container, the problem is you skipped the assignment to your bus variable.  I normally put this in Global.asax Application_Startup, but this way should work too.

If you **are** using a container, and you register the class that implements your ServiceContract, you can get away with having a local IBus constructor/property injected when it's instantiated.

```
public IBus bus { get; set; }

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnStartup(e);

   bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With() // keep a reference to the returned bus. 
           .Log4Net()
           .SpringBuilder()
           .XmlSerializer()
           .MsmqTransport()
           .UnicastBus()
           .LoadMessageHandlers()
           .CreateBus()
           .Start();
}
```